# Datetime picker not working on input with existing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with the datetimepicker. I have a form that has date inputs. These inputs work on submit. However, The form can be edited, and when a user goes to edit a form all the inputs are filled in with their(users) info.

For some reason, when I click on the calendar button for the date input when data is already there, a small circle with a line appears, and doesn't let me pick a new date.

If I go into the input and delete the date, then I can pick a new date with the picker. This however will write as an empty date in the db on submit.

```js
$('.date').datetimepicker({
  formatDate: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  pickTime: false
});
```

```html
<td class="text-left">
  <div class="input-group date required">
    <input type="text" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_start_date]" value="<?php echo $component_module['component_start_date']; ?>" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn" id="component-calendar-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: jquery 2.1.1  bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: What is in `$component_module['component_start_date']`? You need to be sure that `$component_module['component_start_date'] = date('Y-m-d');` Also check this article about [valid formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).